# Does enigmail for thunderbird encrypt title of message

Tags: encryption, thunderbird

From what I've read, encrypting an email with pgp/mime with thunderbird+enigmail will encrypt the entire message including attachments.

Does this also include the message subject title? If not, is there a way to do that with enigmail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Message headers (which the subject is one of) can't be encrypted.

If the subject is sensitive, leave it blank.

http://www.mozilla-enigmail.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=328#p2724

> This is an ever coming back request and my answer is always the same: Enigmail implements/supports the standards available for encrypting&signing emails. These are defined in RFC 4880 (OpenPGP) and RFC 3156 (PGP/MIME). I will not implement any Enigmail-specific solution that is not defined in a standard, and therefore the subject is currently not encrypt-able.

Comment: And cannot be signed. Both is possible in principle but needs a new standard. Unfortunately support for such an extension seems to be quite low among cryppies.